# "Table Data Import Wizard" option missing from drop-down menu

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a schema with a few tables, each containing three or four columns.

I'd like to import some CSV data but can't seem to find the right option. I've right-clicked on the tables expecting there to be a "Table Data Import Wizard" and "Table Data Export Wizard" sandwiched between "Copy to Clipboard" and "Send to SQL Editor".

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Can somebody please offer some guidance?

---

Environment characteristics:

- MySQL version: 5.5.57
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: I faced the same issue. I upgraded to 6.3.8 to solve it. All the GA releases I tried had the same issue. So I looked for previous releases.